# brew mongodb-community: can't connect to localhost database

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I'm trying to connect to a localhost database with mongodb-community 4.2.2, but I'm having connection refused:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-01-17T14:49:50.057+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 
127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 
127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-01-17T14:49:50.060+0100 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-01-17T14:49:50.060+0100 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I don't know what is going on. I tried:

> brew uninstall --force mongodb-community
>
> rm -rf /homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
>
> rm -rf /Cellar/mongodb-community/ folder
>
> brew update
>
> brew install mongodb-community

And all kind of approaches, but nothing solved my problem...

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install mongodb through brew, try running this command to start it:

mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb

Answer (score 2):

Try following these instructions: [LINK](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Then manually delete the content within ***/usr/local/var/mongodb***.

Finally, restart the mongodb-community service.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

To reconnect DB, just run the command that @user129916 suggested.

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

If the error is "Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied":

1. Delete the file:

   /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2. Set the mongoDB configuration file:

   mongod -f /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
3. Set path to DB

   sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was caused by a combination of IPV6 and /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock permission after the update. I fixed it by completely removing mongo and the .sock reinstalling and also adding ipv6 to the config.

Steps below:

1. Completely remove mongodb-community

- `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community`
- `brew cleanup`

2. Recreate mongodb directory

- `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mongodb`
- `cd /usr/local/var && mkdir mongodb`

3. Remove /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

- `cd /tmp`
- `sudo rm -rf mongodb-27017.sock`

4. Reinstall mongodb-community

- `brew install mongodb-community`
- `brew services start mongodb-community`
- `brew services list`
  *Possibly optional. Needed to call restart since it had a permission error wanting sudo but it didn't like that and restart seemed to work without sudo*
- `brew services restart mongodb-community`

If your error says something like `... ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017` also add the following steps

5. Update mongod.conf to also accept IPV6

- `vi /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` *or your preferred editor*

6. Add

```
  ipv6: true
  bindIp: ::1, 127.0.0.1
```